# Why cant I access the methods within my base class in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object

I am trying to have my class number output the variable result from another class. however once run it displays. Error CS0103: The name 'result' does not exist in the current context. Can someone tell me how I can fix this? How can I call the method getMax correctly?

```
using System;

namespace Bank
{

    class FindMax
    {
        public int setMax(int numOne, int numTwo)
        {
            int result;

            if (numOne >= numTwo)
                result = numOne;
            else
                result = numTwo;

            return result;
        }


    }

    class Number : FindMax
    {
        public void getMax()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FindMax mx = new FindMax();
            Number n = new Number();
            mx.setMax(20, 12);
            n.getMax();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `result` is not a class member, it is a local variable defined inside the `setMax` method. You can not access it (or rather, it does not exist) outside of this method, even within the same class.

Comment: I thought by inheriting the FindMax class you inherit all the functions, methods, variables, members of the that class?? correct or not?

Comment: Yes, except the `private` ones. But that is not the issue here. Even within a different method inside the `FindMax` class you can not access the value of `result` because it is a method-local variable. It has no existence outside the execution of the method. Clearly you meant to define it as a class member variable.

Comment: @Novice_29 Yes, but it doesn't inherit the **defintion of the methods**, and cannot change it. You cannot access to a local variable of a method not inside this method. It should be a class member, or a return value, or a `ref` or `out` parameter, so you could change it.

Comment: I see.... Ive placed a public int result in between classFindMax{} and the method. Ive tried running the program but now it displays 0 instead of the correct value. Are you saying the return value of the setMax method only exists within the method and not in other classes??

Comment: The first problem is that you don't store the result of set max in a class variable and that's why tou can't access it from another method. You should read a bit about variable scope in c#. The second problem is the way you use the set and get methods. You have two instances, one of the base class, mx and one for the child class, n. And because of that, the get method will return 0. (That if you fix the first problem.) You should use n for both get and set.

Answer (score 1):

You defined `result` as a local variable inside `setMax()`, so `getMax()` cannot access it. So, you should fix the code:

```
class FindMax
{
    protected int Result; // Not private, because Number (inherits from FindMax) should access it.

    public int setMax(int numOne, int numTwo)
    {
        if (numOne >= numTwo)
            Result = numOne;
        else
            Result = numTwo;

        return Result;
    }
}

class Number : FindMax
{
    public void getMax()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought by inheriting the FindMax class you inherit all the functions, methods, variables, members of the that class?? correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

result is a local variable, and you can not access it from Number class. You should set it at a property of your base class:

```
using System;

namespace Bank
{

    class FindMax
    {
        protected int max;

        public void setMax(int numOne, int numTwo)
        {
            if (numOne >= numTwo)
                max = numOne;
            else
                max = numTwo;
        }


    }

    class Number : FindMax
    {
        public void getMax()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(max);
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Number n = new Number();
            n.setMax(20, 12);
            n.getMax();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No! You should use `n.setMax()`, and don't create an instance of `FindMax`. Changing the variable `max` of `mx` (which is of the type `FindMax`), won't change this variable of `n`, because this variable isn't static!

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable in getMax is not defined.
You can do  something like this

```
class Number : FindMax
    {
        public void getMax(int result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
```

and then call

```
var max = mx.setMax(20, 12);
n.getMax(max);
```

Comment: Can you get return values from methods from other classes??

Comment: Yes, but you will have to use a field to store the result like in the other answer, in this case you don't need to. In the code you posted the variable result is scoped in the function not the class, so you cannot access it from another method.  To access a variable from another method you need to elevate its scope by making it a field

Comment: Can you inherit from multiple classes for example: className : ClassIWantToUse : ClassIAlsoWantToUse????

Comment: In C# you can not inherit from multiple classes like ClassA: ClassB, ClassC, but you can do ClassB inherits classC (ClassB: ClassC{}) and then do ClassA:ClassB